# Integrating JIRA Enterprise with GitHub Enterprise - Required Access Rights?

Tags: github, jira, github-enterprise

I’m attempting to integrate JIRA Enterprise and GitHub Enterprise for certain repositories within our organization.

While following the official documentation, I’m encountering confusion regarding the necessary access rights for both JIRA and GitHub Enterprise.

As this involves an organizational setting, there’s a possibility that I might face challenges in obtaining the required accesses. Can someone provide clarity on the specific rights and accesses needed for a successful integration between JIRA Enterprise and GitHub Enterprise? Any insights or guidance on this matter would be greatly appreciated.